# Sending 2 Lists In A Class From Postman

Tags: c#, json, list, post, postman

these are my classes.

```
public class BasketClass
{
    public int HowMany { get; set; }
    public int MBasketId { get; set; }
    public int MVendorId { get; set; }
    public int WInvestorId { get; set; }
    public int MProductId { get; set; }
}

public class VendorPay
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int MVendorId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCargoIncluded { get; set; }
    public decimal CargoAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}

public class PayBasketInputClass
{
    public List<BasketClass> mOrderList { get; set; }
    public List<VendorPay> vendorPayList { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my method.

```
public IActionResult PayBasket(int WInvestorId, PayBasketInputClass payInput, string paymenttype)
```

I gotta send payInput from body. But it includes two lists and its to complicated for me. Can you help me how to do it with an example?

Cheers.

Comment: if 2 lists too much for you, send 1. Show the code to us and tell what is the problem?

Comment: What is your endpoint? Does WInvestorId and paymenttype come from route or header? Without this kind of information endpoint request cannot be built. Note: you can use swagger. It is used for document but I think it can help you to build request.

Comment: i get investorid and paymenttype as parameter. i just need an example of sending a body from PayBasketInputClass. @AdemCatamak

Comment: idd there is no problem in endpoint cuz its not relevant. I just dont know how to send a body from PayBasketInputClass. It includes 2 lists and I dont know how to send it from postman. I just need an example :D @Serge

Comment: Its a bit unclear but you are essentially asking how to send both lists as part of a JSON response via a Web API right? PayBasketInputClass should have no issue serializing, you can use NewtonSoft to handle this for you with ease. What the JSON will look like is 2 fields, each of which are JSON arrays, populated with JSON objects to mirror the inheritance pattern of the class itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```json
{
    "mOrderList": [
        {
            "HowMany": 1,
            "MBasketId": 2,
            "MVendorId": 3,
            "WInvestorId": 4,
            "MProductId": 5
        }
    ],
    "vendorPayList": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "MVendorId": 2,
            "IsCargoIncluded": true,
            "CargoAmount": 3.99,
            "TotalAmount": 4.99
        }
    ]
}
```

Json object is above is your PayBasketInputClass object in json structure.

Comment: thanks a lot. Should I add "PayBasketInputClass": "..." to the beginning or something like this?

Comment: @MertÇakar no, the { } means that it's an object in JSON. When you convert the JSON to an object in C# (serializing) you tell C# that it's a PayBasketInputClass so C# can fetch the properties to fill with reflection. JSON doesn't need to know the name.